# How do I fetch a specific version of file to /tmp with git in linux?

Tags: git

That is, I don't want to replace the work space,

but fetch a older version of file to `/tmp`?

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
git show $commitid:$filename > /tmp/$filename
```

Writes version `$commitid` of file `$filename` to `/tmp/$filename`.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't extract single file from remote repo
- You can use git-archive in order to get minimail possible part or tree for needed changeset and remove unwanted files
- You can `git checkout cs` in order to return to changeset, copy file out of tree and return back to HEAD `git checkout`

git man is your best friend